# how to know if i reached a far line's height?

Tags: inkscape

Lets say i want to draw a rectangle with a height of a selected line. However the line is far away from my drawing area. How i can know i reached line's height while iam drawing?

Here is the exact problem i am facing if you want to see. I want to add a little rectangle to the big one. However i want their bottom line be same.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at [snapping](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Snapping.html) and [guides](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Snapping.html#Snapping-Guide).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of solving your objective would be to drag a guide from the top ruler until it snaps to a node of your bottom line.

The first image shows the guide after it intersects the left node of the drawing:

[image: snap ruler guide to drawing]

The second image shows the line snapping to the guide. If you require it to be vertical or otherwise orthogonal, hold the control key as you drag:

[image: snap line to guide]

Comment: how to create a guide line? i saw something like "left mouse drag from a ruler onto canvas" sorry but english is not my native can you make this sentence more simple for me. already accepted tho. thanks.

Comment: The description is correct. Place your mouse on the ruler bar at the top or left of the editing window. Hold the button down and move downward or rightward until you've placed the guide line where you require, then release the mouse button. In this example, you'll see the tool tip appear when the snap engages the existing node as shown in the first image.